# Comparison between Random Forest an Bayesian Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, random-forest

I want to implement a language classifier like Linguist in Github:-
http://www.github.com/github/linguist

I don't know if Random forest is better than Bayesian in terms of complexity.
There would be lot of sample data to train for each programming language.

Can Random forest outperform bayesian?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not very experienced, and you don't use toooo many features ( and they are not too sparse ), then random forest will probably work just fine.